# Problem with wsdl in python (convert php to python)

Tags: php, python, web-services, wsdl, suds

Hi I'm trying to connect to a WebService with python.
I have the Php documentation , but i couldn't convert to python.

I have tried suds package like below

```
from suds.client import Client
url = "http://newwebservice.esaj.ir/api/topup"
```

here is the Php documentation:

```
$client = new nusoap_client('http://newwebservice.esaj.ir/api/topup', 'wsdl');
$res = $client->call('getTopup',['username','pass','phone number','price','product','order_id','type','profile_id','ext_id']) ;
print_r($res) ;
```

How can i convert the php code to python?
specifically how can i call "getTopup" in python?

when i try the following code:

```
print(client.service.getTopup())
```

result is:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'promotePrefixes'
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you researched about how to consume a service in python? It's the first step to go about this. Then come back here if having issues with your python code.

Comment: yes i have searched , and done some examples too , but in this specific example i have problem with call(getTopup...)

Comment: Then post the part you are having trouble with, so the community can actually help you.

Comment: how to call getTopup in pyhton

Answer (score 0):

it was "suds" problem , I am using Zeep(Python SOAP client) now , and it's working.

Thanks.